# UI concerns affecting domain design

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a fairly simple domain, with around 7-8 major entities identified and these could be their own aggregate roots. But there is going to be a UI screen that is going to list union of all objects in the system, that would mean union of all aggregates.

One way I have in mind is to use composition, i.e a Metadata aggregate that all other aggregate roots refer to, this will be an independent entity. So for this screen I can query this aggregate, the fields that I move to this new aggregate are the common fields that needs to be displayed in my "All Objects" grid.

The other approach could be to have an application service method that builds the necessary list for "All objects" screen by querying the other repositories and merging the lists at the application layer and also handling paging etc.

I am uneasy with the first solution as I can see a UI use case influencing my 
domain design but the db does the grunt work of handling paging, merging lists etc 
and there are no joins all of these info gleaned out by a single, simple query.

The second solution, although looks neater, loses out on ease and performance.

Please advise.

Comment: I think you just described a case where reads and writes should be separated (you know, that little pattern called cqrs). How fresh does that "all objects" data need to be? You could choose to do explicit asynchronous projection, or define a view over your data (a bit like what that metadata was for (btw, its not an aggregate)) or even use a different path (query) in your code to get the data you want.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would propose the use of [read-models](http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/25/read-models-as-a-tactical-pattern-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/) which are essentially value objects or DTOs used specifically for read scenarios. Use of read-models is a pattern of keeping your entities and ARs clean. As far as how the read-models are created, you have two options basically as you described. One is to have a one repository return a single read-model that fulfills the requirements of a given view. This would allow you to leverage the database for performance. Another option is to compose read-models from multiple repositories or services at the application service level or event at the presentation layer. This approach is more extensible in that data doesn't have to come from the same data source.